# vb.net caching database tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net, recordset

I had a program that was running fine. But I want to speed up my program's running speed.

Old code is something like this:

```
Public Funtion CalcSomething(Byval IncID as int16) as double
    Dim rs as adodb.recordset()=cn.execute("SELECT A,B,C,D,.....(around 10 values) FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.A=t2.A LEFT JOIN ………………(around 10 tables join together WHERE t1.ID=" & IncID)
    Dim Cost1 as double = rs.fields.item("B").value
    Dim AryCost2(19) as double
    For i as int16=0 to 19
        AryCost2(I)=GetCost2(rsX,i,rs.fields.item("A").value,rs.fields.item("C").value)            
    Next I
    Dim Cost2 as double = GetMinValue(AryCost2)

    Return Cost1 + Cost2 
End function

Public Function GetCost2(ByVal I as int16,ByVal A as int16,ByVal B as int16) as double
    Value=DoSomeCalculate(I,A,B)
    Dim rs as adodb.recordset()=cn.execute("SELECT X FROM tableX WHERE Value=" & Value)
    Do while Not rs.EOF
        if FindSuitableOne(rs.fields.item("X").value) then
            Return rs.fields.item("X").value
        End if
    rs.movenext()
    Loop
    return -1
end function
```

I thought getting value from tableX 20 times will be a wasting of time, so I try to cache the whole table and use Filter to find the related rows:

```
Public Funtion CalcSomething(Byval IncID as int16) as double
    Dim rs as adodb.recordset()=cn.execute("SELECT A,B,C,D,.....(around 10 values) FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.A=t2.A LEFT JOIN ………………(around 10 tables join together WHERE t1.ID=" & IncID)
    \\Cache whole table into rsX
    Dim rsX as adodb.recordset()=cn.execute("SELECT X FROM tableX")
    Dim Cost1 as double = rs.fields.item("B").value
    Dim AryCost2(19) as double
    For i as int16=0 to 19
        AryCost2(I)=GetCost2(rsX,i,rs.fields.item("A").value,rs.fields.item("C").value)            
    Next I
    Dim Cost2 as double = GetMinValue(AryCost2)
    Return Cost1 + Cost2 
End function

Public Function GetCost2(byval rsX as adodb.recordset,ByVal I as int16,ByVal A as int16,ByVal B as int16) as double
    Value=DoSomeCalculate(I,A,B)
    rsX.Filter="Value=" & Value) <----this step takes even longer than a new query, I want to ask if there 
    Do while Not rsX.EOF
        if FindSuitableOne(rsX.fields.item("X").value) then
            Return rsX.fields.item("X").value
        End if
    rsX.movenext()
    Loop
    return -1
end function
```

But I found that the Filter method cost longer than a new query. Is there any better method that I can loop through a table with specify value key?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a single joined query, like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(Byval ClassGroup as int16)
    Dim rsStudent as adodb.recordset()

    rsStudent=cn.execute("SELECT tblStudent.StudentID FROM tblStudent INNER JOIN tblClass ON tblStudent.ClassID = tblClass.ClassID WHERE tblClass.ClassGroup = " & ClassGroup)
    Do While Not rsStudent.EOF
        DoSomethingOnStudent(rsStudent.fields.item("StudentID").value)
        rsStudent.movenext
    Loop
End Sub
```

This way, querying the DB only once, your execution should be faster. Also avoid using `*` in select clause, if possible, and only retrieve the columns you need (I see you only use `StudentID` column from the table).

Comment: I am afraid I cannot do that. I try to simplify my situation but it seems I made too simple. I should have re-ask my question.....

Comment: You can probably increase `Filter` performance using indexes. See [Optimize Property-Dynamic (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/optimize-property-dynamic-ado?view=sql-server-2017), provided you are quering an SQL Server data source. I've never userd such a propery anyway.

Comment: I couldn't find out how to do on ADODB yet, but I believe it's a good direction. I will keep finding the answer. Thank you.